# jQuery form.submit() unresponsive script error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I keep getting an unresponsive script error (on Firefox, in Chrome the page just freezes).

I'm using this on Wordpress, where the goal is to send some data through to Wordpress via AJAX upon form submission, and then force the form to submit. So imagine that I want to track statistics for form submissions. The tracking is actually working okay, but whenever it gets to the point where it's submitting the form, the page freezes and I get the jQuery error.

Here is my code (basically):

```
$('.wrapper form').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var self = this;
var data = "x";
    var ajax_url = "correctUrl";
var submission_data = "action=ajax_url" + "&data=" + data;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajax_url,
    data: submission_data,
    success: function(msg) {
        if (data == 'y') {
            if (msg && msg != 'no_redirect') {
                window.location.href = msg;
            }
        } else {
            self.submit();
            if (data == 'x') {
                if (msg != 0 && msg != 'no_redirect') {
                    window.location.href = msg;
                }
            }
        }
    },
}); 
}
```

Comment: what's the point adding code below `self.submit();` when it submits the form manually rather than via ajax?

Comment: I want the form to submit, but I'm stopping that from happening with e.preventDefault() so that I can first track the submission

Comment: thats just going to keep looping isn't it? if (data == 'y') and data is set to x, in which case it submits again?

Comment: so you want to submit via ajax, then if that fails, submit the form manually (non-ajax)?

Comment: I think that @mikevoermans might have a point, I'm not sure how that works though, I thought I was following the jQuery documentation.

Comment: @Joseph imagine what I want to do is just track the statistics for how many times the form gets submitted. So the user clicks "submit", it sends the data via ajax, and then the form goes off and performs it's action.

Comment: i can't seem to understand the logic after success. if there's data and a reply, redirect to location. else.. submit form? submit form as in try again? or is it the normal submit?

Comment: I understand that it's a little confusing; I had to simplify it for this discussion, but it does make sense. If x, then just redirect after ajax request. Else, submit the form (which may be a popup, perhaps, and does not take the user away from the current page), and then redirect to some url.

Answer (score 0):

first step, you hav to set `ajax_url` - replace `correctUrl`  with zour URL.
the second one `var submission_data = "action="+ ajax_url + "&data=" + data;`

Comment: yeah I just put that in as a placeholder. I do have the correct url.

Comment: That's why I specifically set var self = this earlier on, and then use that to submit.

Comment: I set self = this, and then I use "self" later on so that I do not have to use "this" anymore, once the reference is lost.

Comment: And what about this / $(this). Are you shure you need to save a property instead reference? Even so, it seems to me, tha script goes to the loop. After  self.submit(); (if is successfull) data is set to x and then the Submit() repeats.